# block any click if modal is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<body>
<div id='container'>
<div id='cpanel' style="position:fixed;">525</div>
</div>
<div class='modal' style="position:fixed;>323</div>
</body>
```

I want to prevent any click on `container` and its children if `modal` is visible.

**js**

```
$('#container, #cpanel').click(function(){
    if ($('.modal').is(':visible')) {return false;}
});
```

Click on `container` is blocked, but on `cpanel` is not !

Any help?

Comment: I believe it is safe to say the typical way to "block" interactions with the page under a modal is to make an overlay, so the clicks click the overlay and not the content under it.  I would suggest researching this option.

Comment: It is not that simple as you think. You can't just put your event on top of the stack. The comment above seems to be the only reliable solution.

Comment: @FlashThunder what about `event stack` in case of `Rohit.007` solution?

Comment: @puerto that is totally different solution... and has nothing to do with events, but styles. That won't work with older browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution can consider the CSS [pointer-event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) property.

If you are using the jquery ui dialog you can add the code to the events:

- [open( event, ui )](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-open)
- [close( event, ui )](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-close) (the code for removing the newly added style)

```js
$('.modal').dialog({
    open: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#cpanel').css('pointer-events','none');
    },
    close: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#cpanel').css('pointer-events','auto');
    },
});

$('#container, #cpanel').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('--->clicked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div id='container'>
    <div id='cpanel' style="position:fixed;">525</div>
</div>
<div class='modal' style="position:fixed;">323</div>
```

Comment: Would you not set this property when the modal opens?  Also do you need to set it on the cpanel as it is a child of the container?

Comment: it works even without `return false`. But `came back` is needed after `modal` is closed,

Answer (score -1):

Try stopPropagation method:

```
$('#container, #cpanel').on("click", function(event){
    if ($('.modal').is(':visible')) {
       event.stopPropagation()
    }
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zjywXV

Comment: it won't work because `cpanel` has it's own `onclick` event... and you can't put your code in the top of events stack.

Comment: What about  stopPropagation instead of preventDefault?

Comment: `stopPropagation` is a very dangerous thing. Pleas search this thing on Google.